# Data is lost after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got one ajax call after two previous. I need to pass results of those calls to the new one, so I do the following

```
    $.when(getRespData(), getAxisComponents()).done(function (respData, axisData) {
     var a = respData; //everything is ok
     var b = axisData; //everything is ok
     $.ajax({
           dataType: "json",
           url: '/rest/visualization/' + taskName + '/workload?runName=' + runName+ '&type=' + 'VAL',
           success: (function (data) {
              var c = respData; //everything is ok
              var d = axisData; // Uncaught ReferenceError: axisData is not defined
           }
```

but I've got Uncaught ReferenceError when I try to get my axisData inside my new ajax call, although operations with respData are ok. 
My first 2 ajax calls look like

```
function getRespData() {
   return $.ajax({
     dataType: "json",
     url: '/rest/visualization/' + taskName + '/workload?runName=' + runName + '&type=' + 'RESP',
     success: (function (data) {
          return data;
   })
 });
```

}

```
function getAxisComponents() {
  return $.ajax({
     dataType: "json",
     url: '/rest/visualization/' + taskName + '/workload/axis?runName=' + runName,
     success: (function (data) {
          return data;
   })
 });
```

}

where runName, type, taskName are some params of function which contains all these ajax calls.
How can I fix this error, so that I would be able to access both respData and axisData ind my inner ajax call?

Comment: are you sure that `axisData` is ever set? does the ajax call run successfully?

Comment: yes, my ajax call run succesfully. I need 'return data'  just to get some json data from the response

Comment: You wrote `everything is ok`. Please check what the output is for `console.log(respData)` and `console.log(axisData)`. Are they valid json objects?

Comment: Seems to work fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/dq5515pd/8/

Answer (score 2):

i solved it putting async false and declaring an array out of ajax call, like this

```
let array = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            array = response;
        }
    });
    return array;
```

Answer (score -2):

You're calling data in your success function but data isn't set before this.

In a jQuery .ajax function, data is the data that is sent to the server when performing the Ajax request, which is why you may think it is lost (because it was never there).

Consider the following:

```js
$.ajax({
  data: {"data": data},
  dataType: "json",
  url: 'yourURl',
  success: function(data){
    return data;
 }
```

Comment: Data is transferred normally, I've checked it with the debugger